# How can I manage to make diffrent request after first request with failed status

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I try to fetch some object, but the problem is that I need to check first if there ist any object on cache endpoint, if not I should do normal fetching from regular endpoint.

So far I only managed to do fetching from:

1. Normal endpoint and set everything on state,
2. Cache endpoint and set everything on state

Any attempts to mix both methods ended in failure :(

How can I mix this two methods?

```
const getCache = async () => {
  try {
    const apiCall = await fetch(fetchCacheEndpoint)
    const data = await apiCall.json()
    return data
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

}
const pageOne = getCache().then((result) => {
  const convertedOBj = result.doSomeSeriousStuff()
  this.setState({
     desiredObj: convertedOBj 
  })
})
```

I expected to do something like this

```
const getCache = async () => {
  try {
    const apiCall = await fetch(fetchCacheEndpoint)
    const data = await apiCall.json()
    return data
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
let convertedOBj 
const pageOne = getCache().then((result) => {
 if ((result === undefined) || (!result) || (result && !result.length > 0)) {
    const makeRegularFetch = async () => {
      const regularFetch = await fetch(regularEndPoint)
      const data = await regularFetch.json()
    }
    const pageTwo = makeRegularFetch ().then((result) => {
      convertedOBj = result.doSomeSeriousStuff()
      this.setState({
        desiredObj: convertedOBj 
      })
    })
 } else {
   convertedOBj = result.doSomeSeriousStuff()
   this.setState({
     desiredObj: convertedOBj 
   })
 }

})
```

After first fetch (getCache) is failed there is another fetch (makeRegularFetch) to second endpoint which is always fine, but only in the case when first(getCache) return empty object or just any kind of error
How can I handle this kind of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your second part of your code, you never execute your `pageOne` function.

Try `pageOne()` after your definition.

However I made a fiddle on stackblitz for your case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-eufm8h

If you don't understand something, feel free to ask.